# Why is $(T-\lambda I)^pT(x) = T(T-\lambda I)^p(x)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Definition. Let $T$ be a linear operator on a vector space $V$, and let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$. The generalized eigenspace of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda_1$ denoted $K_\lambda$, is the subset of $V$ defined by
>
> $K_\lambda$ = $\{x \in V: (T-\lambda  I)^p(x) = 0$ for some positive integer $p\}$.
>
> To show that $K_\lambda$ is $T$-invariant, consider any $x \in K_\lambda$. Choose a positive integer $p$ such that $(T-\lambda)^p = 0$. Then
>
> $(T-\lambda  I)^pT(x) = T(T-\lambda I)^p(x) = T(0) = 0$

I wanted to know how we go from $(T-\lambda  I)^pT(x) = T(T-\lambda I)^p(x)$?

Comment: Induction on $p$? Or write $T$ as $(T-\lambda I)+\lambda I$?

Comment: Take both expressions and expand out $(T-\lambda I)^p$ using the binomial theorem. After simplifying, you will find there are equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $T$ commutes with both $T$ and $\lambda\operatorname{Id}$, $T$ commutes with $T-\lambda\operatorname{Id}$ and therefore it comutes with any power of $T-\lambda\operatorname{Id}$.